# Change axis for CSS3 perspective animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to build a css3 folding effect. Here is an example of the effect, but built in Objective-C: http://vimeo.com/41495357

Current version: http://jsfiddle.net/ctdNE/2/

My Problem is the axis of the animation. At the moment, the axis of the animation is vertical centered. Is it possible to shift it to the left of the animated container? Cause of the centered axis, the height of the container gets bigger during the animation. If the axis could be at the very left, the height wouldn't change.

Enclose a picture which explains my problem:

[animation http://gopeter.de/animation.png](http://gopeter.de/animation.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

Use (-webkit-)transform-origin to shift the axis.